# Can't edit postgresql.conf file to change settings

Tags: postgresql, logging, postgresql.conf

After editing `postgresql.conf` file and restarting a server it seems that all changes do not apply.

I was following this tutorial:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/pgadmin-4-server-status-view-log-file?newreg=9500cbcc4a794d2fbfd6ef5bb787e0e5
To create `.csv` log files for postgresql database. In PGAdmin 4 I've run

```
 SELECT sourcefile FROM pg_settings
```

and

```
SHOW config_file
```

that showed me path of conf file: `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`
I've located and edited that file on my Debian server through midnight commander and changed lines:

```
log_destination='csvlog'
logging_collector='on'
log_directory ='log'
log_filename='postgresql.log'
```

And then I've restarted the server

```sh
sudo service postgresql restart
```

And now I have problems. I can't find `.csv` logs that are supposed to be saved on a server in '`log`' directory. There is no such directory in `/etc/postgresql/10/main` or var`/lib/postgresql/10/main`. The only logs I could have found were on var/log/posgresql, but there aren't any `.csv` files I was searching for. Also I'm not sure if any of my edits in `postgresql.conf` file are even working, because I checked the setting from pgAdmin and thats what I got:

```
SHOW log_destination
stderr

SHOW logging_collector
off
```

So it looks like settings from `postgresql.conf` are not properly applied. How to properly set `.csv` logs for postgresql and where they can be found?

Comment: Can you see the new settings in `pg_settings`?

Comment: I checked: SELECT * FROM pg_settings, and it seems that log_destination = stderr, logging_collector = off, log_filename = postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log. postgresql.conf file on server is saved and have new values

Comment: And what did you see? The new or the old settings?

Comment: Old settings in PGAdmin

Comment: If the server started, there cannot have been a syntax error in the configuration file. So either you changed the wrong configuration file, or you connected to the wrong server.